# Prolog - Comparison between 1 and 0.5 fails

Tags: prolog

I have a very basic function which basically does comparison of the input numbers with some constants.
Here is the code -

```
check(FEATURE_0, FEATURE_1, FEATURE_2, FEATURE_3, FEATURE_4, FEATURE_5) :-
    FEATURE_0 =< 37.95 ->
       FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 -> //Fails here with error Fail: >/2
            write("Class 3")
        ;FEATURE_3 > 0.5 ->
            write("Class 1")
    ;FEATURE_0 > 37.95 ->
        FEATURE_2 =< 0.5 ->
            write("Class 3")
        ;FEATURE_2 > 0.5 ->
            FEATURE_4 =< 0.5 ->
                write("Class 2")
            ;FEATURE_4 > 0.5 ->
                FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 ->
                    write("Class 2")
                    ;write("Class 0").
```

Apart from `FEATURE_0` every other value is always going to be either 1 or 0. However, the code fails at line 3 stating `Fail: >/2`. I have just started trying out prolog as part of an assignment so my experience with this is zero, however, from what I know, I suspect this has something to do with comparing an integer with a float value. I want to know what's the issue here and how can I fix this.

Comment: Please give an example question for your predicate, state what the outcome is if you ask that question and describe what outcome you expect instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get that error in SWI-Prolog, but I do get "Singleton variables: [FEATURE_1,FEATURE_5]".

Note that the expression as it is written does not correspond to the intended meaning as can be derived from the indentation:

The first `;` (the one before `FEATURE_3`) is the "topmost" functor name. This can be (awkwardly) ascertained by printing the body through `write_canonical/2`:

```
?- write_canonical((
|        FEATURE_0 =< 37.95 ->
|           FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 ->
|                write("Class 3")
|            ;FEATURE_3 > 0.5 ->
|                write("Class 1")
|        ;FEATURE_0 > 37.95 ->
|            FEATURE_2 =< 0.5 ->
|                write("Class 3")
|            ;FEATURE_2 > 0.5 ->
|                FEATURE_4 =< 0.5 ->
|                    write("Class 2")
|                ;FEATURE_4 > 0.5 ->
|                    FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 ->
|                        write("Class 2")
|                        ;write("Class 0"))).
```

which gives (reformatted by hand):

```
;(->(=<(A,37.95),->(=<(B,0.5),write("Class 3"))),
   ;(->(>(B,0.5),write("Class 1")),
      ;(->(>(A,37.95),->(=<(C,0.5),write("Class 3"))),
         ;(->(>(C,0.5),->(=<(D,0.5),write("Class 2"))),
            ;(->(>(D,0.5),->(=<(B,0.5),write("Class 2"))),
                write("Class 0")
             )
         )
      )
    )
  )
```

The original code being very hard to read, maintain, and I understand, I recommend this:

```
check(F0, _, F2, F3, F4, _) :-
   check_f0(F0,F2,F3,F4).

check_f0(F0, _,F3,_ ) :- F0 =< 37.95, check_f3(F3).
check_f0(F0,F2,F3,F4) :- F0 >  37.95, check_f2(F2,F3,F4).

check_f3(F3)          :- F3 =< 0.5, write("Class 3").
check_f3(F3)          :- F3 >  0.5, write("Class 1").

check_f2(F2,_,_)      :- F2 =< 0.5, write("Class 3").
check_f2(F2,F3,F4)    :- F2 >  0.5, check_f4(F4,F3).

check_f4(F4,_)        :- F4 =< 0.5, write("Class 2").
check_f4(F4,F3)       :- F4 >  0.5, check_f3x(F3).

check_f3x(F3)         :- F3 =< 0.5, write("Class 2").
check_f3x(F3)         :- F3 >  0.5, write("Class 0").
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is working as expected. Not sure why I am getting that error with my original code though.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not parsed in the way you expect (judging from your indentation), but is equivalent to

```
check(FEATURE_0, FEATURE_1, FEATURE_2, FEATURE_3, FEATURE_4, FEATURE_5) :-
    ( FEATURE_0 =< 37.95 ->
        ( FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 ->
            write("Class 3")
        )
    ; FEATURE_3 > 0.5 ->
        write("Class 1")
    ; FEATURE_0 > 37.95 ->
        ...
    ).
```

which explains the failure you get.  Best practice is to *always* surround the if-then-else construct with parentheses, i.e. `( Cond -> Then ; Else )`, viz

```
check(FEATURE_0, FEATURE_1, FEATURE_2, FEATURE_3, FEATURE_4, FEATURE_5) :-
    ( FEATURE_0 =< 37.95 ->
        ( FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 ->
            write("Class 3")
        ; FEATURE_3 > 0.5 ->
            write("Class 1")
        )
    ; FEATURE_0 > 37.95 ->
        ( FEATURE_2 =< 0.5 ->
            write("Class 3")
        ; FEATURE_2 > 0.5 ->
            ( FEATURE_4 =< 0.5 ->
                write("Class 2")
            ; FEATURE_4 > 0.5 ->
                ( FEATURE_3 =< 0.5 ->
                    write("Class 2")
                ;
                    write("Class 0")
                )
            )
        )
    ).
```